# Problema con WebView con API Contactos

Tags: flutter, dart, chrome

Soy novato en flutter y quiero hacer un webview similar a Google Chrome, sin embargo tengo una dificultad y es que la web realizada tiene JavaScript para seleccionar una lista de contactos desde el celular (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ContactsManager), y en el navegador de google crhome funciona fin problema, ahora bien he desarrollado una aplicación con webview, pero éste no me permite, me aparece un error "unable to open a contact selector".

Agradezco enormemente la colaboración que me puedan brindar para crear un webview que funcione correctamente, es de resaltar que le tengo los permisos habilitados y al momento de dar clic en Javascript, este solicita el permiso para leer los contactos, pero no abre el listado.